# Flutter TSC Thermal Printer

Tags: flutter, thermal-printer

I am developing a Flutter app, and I’ve been trying to print via bluetooth in a thermal printer. I have found a lot of libraries/package for bluetooth thermal printers, but I need my program to print with TSC Alpha-3RB. But the printer does not appear on the device. I don't know if I need to do anything else about it.

Does someone know some package or method I can try to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Find the compatible SDK from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages?q=thermal+blue+printer)
& here is the list of some flutter SDK's that I used previously:

- [bluetooth_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer) (Only available for Android)
- [blue_print_pos](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_print_pos) (For both Android & iOS)
  This is the updated forked [blue_print_pos SDK](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos/) which I used in Dec, 2022. You can also use it without facing any issues.

### Follow steps to integrate the SDK:

1. First, you need to add the plugin for the Bluetooth thermal printer to your existing Flutter project. You can do this by adding the following dependency to your pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies: 
  flutter_bluetooth_thermal_printer: ^1.0.0
```

2. Import the plugin in your project:

```
import 'package:[PACKAGE_NAME].dart';
```

3. Create a saperate window (UI) to search available printers & after that, you can use the plugin to connect to and print from the Bluetooth thermal printer. For example, you can use the following steps to connect to the printer and print a simple text:
4. First check the bluetooth is `On` or `Off`. You can check bluetooth device using [system_shortcuts](https://pub.dev/documentation/system_shortcuts/latest/) package.

> ```
> // it return true if already bluetooth is turned on
> var isOn = SystemShortcuts.checkBluetooth;
> if (!isOn){
>  // it turn-on the bluetooth
>  await SystemShortcuts.bluetooth();
> }
> ```

5. Scan the device & connect to the printer:

> eg.
>
> ```
> // Connect to the printer 
> FlutterBluetoothThermalPrinter.connect('MY_PRINTER_ID').then((printer) { 
>   // Print text 
>   printer.printString('Hello World!'); 
> });
> ```

6. Now use the print method to print the data on any screen.

Note that this is just a general outline of the process for integrating a Bluetooth thermal printer into a Flutter project. You will need to consult the documentation for the Flutter Bluetooth package and the specific documentation for your printer in order to complete the integration or run the [sample code](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos/tree/master/example).